# Android 10 - Query MediaStore with different Uri types

Tags: java, android, q, mediastore, android-10.0

I have a problem with the android standard picker.
I have the following code to query the mediastore with a uri from the standard picker(call with ACTION_GET_CONTENT):

```
        private AudioRecord getAudioInfo(Uri uri) {
        AudioRecord rec = new AudioRecord();
        try {
            if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, uri)){
                String[] data = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM};
                String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, data, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);
                Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                rec.setData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                rec.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
                rec.setArtist(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
                rec.setAlbum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
                rec.setFilename("8D " + rec.getTitle() + ".mp3");
                cursor.close();
                return rec;
            } else {
                String[] data = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM};
                CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), uri, data, null, null, null);
                Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                rec.setData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                rec.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
                rec.setArtist(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
                rec.setAlbum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
                rec.setFilename("8D " + rec.getTitle() + ".mp3");
                cursor.close();
                return rec;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rec;
        }
    }
```

-

In the picker i have different options to pick a file. These options are shown and numbered in the image below:

[image]

Here are the output Uri's for the different numbers:

1. (Musik:

   > content://media/external/audio/media/3301
2. (Downloads):

   > content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A3301
3. (VOG-L29):

   > content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2FJuice%20WRLD%20Unreleased%2FBag.mp3
4. (Dateien):

   > content://media/external/audio/media/3301
5. (Audio):

   > content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A3301

The code works for all Uri's except number 3. In this Uri there isn't any ID which i can use to query the mediastore.

So the question is:

**How can i use such a Uri to query the mediastore for more informations about artist and so on?**

Comment: "The code works for all Uri's except number 3" -- and many others. There are far more than 5 options. "In this Uri there isn't any ID which i can use to query the mediastore" -- there is no requirement for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to return a `Uri` that references data on the device, let alone one that has something to do with the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Ok. So the only thing i can do, is to try to query the media store and if it fails i have to cancel the process?

Comment: Or, if you only want to deal with things known to the `MediaStore`, you could limit yourself to using the `MediaStore`. For example, you could use `ACTION_PICK` with a `Uri` pointing to a `MediaStore` collection. Or you could `query()` the `MediaStore` and display its results in your own UI.

Comment: ACTION_PICK with "android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" is excactly what i need. Thank you.